# WPF&prism MVVM and Tabitem with an image

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism-6

I have a wpf application with a tab control showing images instead of text on the tabitem.
Now I want to rewrite the whole thing and use prism.
I found an example but there is only a text property bound to the tabitem.
How can I display an image through binding to a viewmodel
(Each module has one tab).

Answer (score 0):

When binding the items to the TabControl, use ItemsSource. The ItemTemplate defines what is shown in the tab header. The ContentTemplate defines what is shown in the tab area.

**View Models**

```
public class ShellViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items
    {
        get;
    } = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();

    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        Items.Add(new ItemViewModel { Name = "First", ImageUri = new Uri("http://placehold.it/50x50") });
        Items.Add(new ItemViewModel { Name = "Second", ImageUri = new Uri("http://placehold.it/40x40") });
        Items.Add(new ItemViewModel { Name = "Third", ImageUri = new Uri("http://placehold.it/30x30") });
    }
}

public class ItemViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private string _name;
    private Uri _imageUri;

    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set => SetProperty(ref _name, value);
    }

    public Uri ImageUri
    {
        get => _imageUri;
        set => SetProperty(ref _imageUri, value);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:WpfApp4.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModels:ShellViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}" Height="20"></Image>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

The above code will show three (3) tabs with the specified image in the tab header. I've dummied up the content with just text.

Comment: Thanx. I know how to do it when I create tabitems myself by code or xaml. But my question was about PRISM. The tabitems are created by PRISM on navigating to a view.